# Hide Gear Icon for a set of users on a communication site

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

We have a communication site where we need to disable the gear icon based on the permissions assigned to the users

I was referring to the below article

https://olafd.wordpress.com/2018/09/17/simple-solution-to-remove-the-gear-icon-in-sharepoint-online/?unapproved=1367&moderation-hash=83f4fa52244ea8c3fe83cc0179e617d7#comment-1367

Followed the steps mentioned in the article , However I come across the below error

[Local File Not Found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HK3ET.jpg)

Below is the Script I am trying to Execute

```
Write-Host "Upload RemoveGearIcon.js"
 
$f = Add-PnPFile -Path .\RemoveGearIcon.js -Folder "scripts"
 
$site = Get-PnPSite
$fileUrl = $site.Url + "/Scripts/RemoveGearIcon.js"
 
Write-Host "Add JavaScript Link"
 
$jsLink = Get-PnPJavaScriptLink -Name "RemoveGearIcon" -Scope Site
 
if ($jsLink -ne $null)
{
    Remove-PnPJavaScriptLink -Identity "RemoveGearIcon" -Scope Site -Force
}
 
$link = Add-PnPJavaScriptLink -Name "RemoveGearIcon" -Url $fileUrl -Sequence 200 -Scope Site
```

I have not been able to figure out what could be going wrong and would appreciate if anyone here could help me with this or let me know any other alternative to get this done.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have a library called "Scripts" on your site.

Please run the code again.

Comment: I have a library named Scripts on the site

Comment: you need to have a local file called "RemoveGearIcon.js".
$f = Add-PnPFile -Path C:\RemoveGearIcon.js -Folder "scripts"